# PreparedStatement execution says MySQLSyntaxErrorException although works in MySQL console

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I've written the following code (snippet):

```
conn = Pooling.getDataSource().getConnection();
String databaseName = Configuration.getDatabaseName();
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + databaseName + ".companies WHERE companyemail = ? AND companypassword = MD5(?)"; 
PreparedStatement prepStat = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
prepStat.setString(1, username);
prepStat.setString(2, password);
System.out.println("LoginService: prepStat = " + prepStat.toString());
ResultSet rs = prepStat.executeQuery(sql);
...
```

Now, when I execute this, I'm getting a `MySQLSyntaxErrorException`. The `prepStat.toString()` prints:

```
SELECT * FROM dbname.companies WHERE companyemail = 'comp@comp.com' AND companypassword = MD5('passwort')
```

And a simple copy and paste to SequelPro successfully return a result.

However, the backend still claims that there is an error in the syntax:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND companypassword = MD5(?)' at line 1
```

Maybee I'm blind but I do not see an error here? But what is happening here?

Comment: What is the size defined for the `companypassword` column?

Comment: The size of `companypassword` is `CHAR(32)` such that a `MD5` hash exactly fits into it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found out what the problem was. I used:

```
ResultSet rs = prepStat.executeQuery(sql);
```

However, I should have used

```
ResultSet rs = prepStat.executeQuery();
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM '" + databaseName + ".companies' WHERE companyemail=? AND companypassword = MD5(?)";
```

Notice the single quote before the databaseName variable and after .companies . I think that could be the problem.

Or you could do this:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM ? WHERE companyemail =? AND companypassword = MD5(?)"; 
PreparedStatement prepStat = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
prepStat.setString(1, databaseName);
prepStat.setString(2, username);
prepStat.setString(3, password);
```

I believe the problem is at the level of parsing the databaseName to the prepared statement.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. But the error remains exactly the same.

Comment: Did you try the second approach?

Comment: Try testing using a statement, just write the query string with the values

Comment: Yeah, if I put it directly inside the query like this `String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + databaseName + ".companies WHERE companyemail = '" + username + "' AND companypassword = MD5('" + password + "')";` it works perfectly fine.

Comment: It fails as soon as I put and `?` and a `prepStat.setString(*, *);` into the query